# Setting up Tomcat through the Cmd line

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, cmd

I am presently trying to get tomcat to run on my computer for a servlet application. If i click the startup shell then the cmd line pops up then disappears. i tried to set up the Environmental variable with the line`JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\JDK1.8.0_45` and `JRE_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\JDK1.8.0_45`  and anytime i try to run `startup` i get the error:

> The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
>   This environment variable is needed to run the program

I have read through the tutorials and do not understand them, so if im missing something obvious please explain it simply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JRE_HOME is jre's path. Under \Java folder, you'll see jre7 probably. Copy its path to JRE_HOME section in environment variables.

Comment: spent 2 hours on that thing

Comment: follow up question how do i open files through tomcat